# Why am I getting Module "Pygame.surface" has no attribute 'get_rect'

Tags: python, pygame

So I have class for a strategy game That I'm making and I'm trying to switch the PNG'S I have for normal pygame squares. However I'm getting the error  -> AttributeError: module 'pygame.surface' has no attribute 'get_rect'

(Full Error) ->

```
File "/Users/wallera/PycharmProjects/--------/main.py", line 20, in <module>
red_region1 = Region(300, 0, "red")
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/wallera/PycharmProjects/------/Region.py", line 21, in __init__
self.rect = self.image_rect.get_rect()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'pygame.surface' has no attribute 'get_rect'
```

This is currently what i have for the class ->

```
class Region:
    def __init__(self, x, y, colour):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.colour = colour

        # Load the correct image file for the colour of this region
        if self.colour == "red":
            self.image = pygame.surface
        elif self.colour == "blue":
            self.image = pygame.image.load("/Users/wallera/PycharmProjects/MAJORPROJECT2/Assets/square_blue_region1.png")
            pass
        else:
            print(f"Unknown colour: {self.colour}")

        # Position the image correctly
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topright = (self.x, self.y)

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
```

and if needed, this is the games main code:

```
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 700))  # The display window

pygame.display.set_caption('Turn Based Strategy Game')  # Name is subject to change
framerate = pygame.time.Clock()  # setting the fps to 60, so it stays consistent and no fluctuations to make it stable



bottom_menu = pygame.Surface((1000, 150))
next_turn_holder = pygame.Surface((250, 225))

bottom_menu.fill('Grey')
next_turn_holder.fill('Grey')

red_region1 = Region(300, 0, "red")
blue_region1 = Region(600, 0, "blue")


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()  # Exit the game

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_TAB:
            pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()

    screen.fill('lightblue')
    red_region1.draw(screen)
    blue_region1.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update()
    #framerate.tick(60)  # maximum framerate
```

I'm not sure why it isn't working and would appreciate any help, I think it might be because surfaces can't be assigned a rect (I have the image there because I am trying to switch from the PNG's as they were aligned very well, I need something that is perfect)

This is my first time using pygame so I'm no super used to it's documentation (Which could use some improvements I believe)

Comment: The traceback doesn't match the shown code (=was produced by another version of the code).

Comment: `self.image = pygame.surface` is probably the problem. `pygame.surface` is the name of a module that defines a `Surface` class.

Comment: @Barmar what do t put in its place?

Comment: I think what you want is `pygame.Surface((height, width))`. I don't know where you get the height and width from in your case, though.

Comment: @Barmar I have it them set as a variable a few lines above the class

Comment: The error implies you did `import pygame.surface`. That doesn't set a variable.

Comment: `self.image = pygame.Surface((height, width))` `self.image.fill(colour)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an image with a uniform color, you have to create a `pygame.Surface` object and fill it with the color:

<s>`self.image = pygame.surface`</s>

```py
self.image = pygame.Surface((height, width), pygame.SRCALPHA)
self.image.fill(colour)
```